# Sending HTML email using SAP Workflow "Send Mail" activity

Tags: workflow, html-email, sap-basis

We have a SAP workflow which uses "Send Mail" activity to send an email to relevant users.

I want to include hyperlinks in this email so that the user can be taken to particular site upon clicking the link in the email.

Click here to view details

However, when the email is viewed in the email client, it is shown in RAW format.

How do I specify Send Mail to send out the email in HTML format??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not a workflow literate, but depending on what you want to do, you will have to code a little bit.

First, if you are just trying to add the hyperlink, you may try putting the following XML tag in your Send Mail task (don’t break the line).

```
<A HREF="&URL&">Link<(><<)>/A>
```

Then, if your e-mail is arriving as plain text, you may have to change the configuration on SCOT transaction, from RAW to HTM. (see explanation link below)

If that don’t work as expected, try coding a custom function module to receive the recipients and hyperlinks, and send the e-mail using SO_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1 FM (or SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_ATT_SEND_API1 FM, or even CL_BCS class ), so that you will have full control over e-mail sending.

Finally, take a look at the following POSTS from SDN

SCOT transaction discussion on workflow hyperlinks: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?messageID=1152432#1152432

And how to use the FM or classes to send emails from workflow step:
http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1948769